# JQuery effects on dynamically created controls inside ASP.NET AJAX update panel

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamic, panel

Hello StakOverflowians!
Wondering whether someone could help with this.

I have a dynamically created  tag inside an AJAX update panel. Upon clicking the  tag, I am trying to (for the time being) display an alert using JQuery. 
The problem is that the alert doesn't get displayed when the  tag is generated dynamically, however, if I declare the  tag statically in .aspx, then it works. 
Here is the code:

```
   protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
       HtmlAnchor htmlA = new HtmlAnchor();
       htmlA.ID = "hidden_link";
       PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(htmlA);

       string javaScriptFunction =
          "jQuery(document).ready(function() {" +
              "$(function () {" +
                  "$(\"a[id$='hidden_link']\").click(function () {" +
                      "alert('Alert: Hello from jQuery!');" +
                  "});" +
              "});" +
          "}";

       ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, 
                                           this.GetType(), 
                                           "myScript", 
                                           javaScriptFunction, 
                                           true); 
   }
```

and on .aspx, I have:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $("a[id$='hidden_link']").click(function() {
                alert("Alert: Hello from jQuery!");
            });
        });
    } 
</script>
```

What should I do to get the alert working for dynamically created controls inside the PlaceHolder1? 
Any help will be most appreciated.

Thanks, 
Ali

Comment: When you say created "dynamically" is it created dynamically by client-side or server-side script?

Comment: **UPDATE** A further elaboration: I basically started from weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2010/10/07/…. The only different/additional thing I want to do is on the click of that button, I want to create a dynamic <a> tag and call its click event. I am registering the script in code-behind as in method 3 of the post.

Answer (score 1):

If you're button click is running in an async post back, you're not actually reloading the page. So, the `$(document).ready()` method won't get called.

To solve your problem, just remove the call.

```
string javaScriptFunction = "$(\"a[id$='hidden_link']\").click(function () { alert('Alert: Hello from jQuery!'); });";
```

Or alternatively, you may find jQuery's [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function more suitable for attaching handlers to elements that are created dynamically

Comment: Thanks for the reply wsanville. Using live() function, I can bind the alert function with the click event of the dynamically created <a> tag. It displays the alert on clicking the <a> tag. However, what I want to achieve is the click event called programmatically, i.e. on clicking the button, the <a> tag is created and then its click event is called.